# Network translation and port forwarding causing host to timeout

Tags: nat, ip

I'm trying to setup a small network, consisting of 3 routers and switches, and one L3 Switch:

[image]

I have activated PAT on both router R1 and R2, to translate from the private IP addresses to the public IP addresses,

When pinging from host Bizerte or the server to the all the public addresses, everything works fine.

I have set up a port forwarding on router R3 to forward all incoming packets on port 80 to the server.

When I telnet from R1 to `41.224.0.3:80` it works fine, and the translation is successful, but when I try to use the same command using the Bizerte host, the translation fails, and checking the server, I can't even ping on the router R3 (`172.16.5.65`).
Checkig the server means pining from the server to R3 router, or vice-versa.

In order to restore connectivity, I have to `shutdown` the interface `e0` (e0 on the R3 router which is directly connected to the server.), and `no shutdown` it again.

Here are the routers configurations:

**R1:**

```
!
version 12.4
service timestamps debug datetime msec
service timestamps log datetime msec
no service password-encryption
!
hostname R1
!
boot-start-marker
boot-end-marker
!
!
no aaa new-model
!
resource policy
!
memory-size iomem 5
no ip icmp rate-limit unreachable
ip cef
!
!
ip tcp synwait-time 5
no ip dhcp use vrf connected
!
ip dhcp pool bizerte
   network 172.16.1.0 255.255.255.0
   default-router 172.16.1.1 
!
!
no ip domain lookup
!
!
!
!
!
! 
!
!
!
interface Ethernet0
 ip address 172.16.1.1 255.255.255.0
 ip nat inside
 ip virtual-reassembly
 half-duplex
!
interface FastEthernet0
 ip address 41.224.0.1 255.255.255.248
 ip nat outside
 ip virtual-reassembly
 speed auto
!
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 41.224.0.6
!
no ip http server
no ip http secure-server
ip nat inside source list 1 interface FastEthernet0 overload
!
access-list 1 permit 172.16.1.0 0.0.0.255
no cdp log mismatch duplex
!
control-plane
!
!
line con 0
 exec-timeout 0 0
 privilege level 15
 logging synchronous
line aux 0
 exec-timeout 0 0
 privilege level 15
 logging synchronous
line vty 0 4
 login
!
end
```

**R3:**

```
!
version 12.4
service timestamps debug datetime msec
service timestamps log datetime msec
no service password-encryption
!
hostname R3
!
boot-start-marker
boot-end-marker
!
!
no aaa new-model
!
resource policy
!
memory-size iomem 5
no ip icmp rate-limit unreachable
ip cef
!
!
ip tcp synwait-time 5
no ip dhcp use vrf connected
ip dhcp excluded-address 172.16.5.65 172.16.5.66
!
ip dhcp pool ariana
   network 172.16.5.64 255.255.255.192
   default-router 172.16.5.65 
!
!
no ip domain lookup
!
!
!
!
!
! 
!
!
!
interface Ethernet0
 ip address 172.16.5.65 255.255.255.192
 ip nat inside
 ip virtual-reassembly
 half-duplex
!
interface FastEthernet0
 ip address 41.224.0.3 255.255.255.248
 ip nat outside
 ip virtual-reassembly
 speed auto
!
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 41.224.0.6
!
no ip http server
no ip http secure-server
ip nat inside source list 1 interface FastEthernet0 overload
ip nat inside source static tcp 172.16.5.66 80 interface FastEthernet0 80
!
access-list 1 permit 172.16.5.64 0.0.0.63
no cdp log mismatch duplex
!
control-plane
!
!
line con 0
 exec-timeout 0 0
 privilege level 15
 logging synchronous
line aux 0
 exec-timeout 0 0
 privilege level 15
 logging synchronous
line vty 0 4
 login
!
end
```

**EDIT:**

From the NAT debug output and Wireshark capture, it seems that the router R3 actually sends a respond to router R1, but router R1 is not routing/forwarding back the response to the host (Bizerte here).

**NAT debug output:**

**Router R1:**

```
*Mar 1 00:20:24.607: NAT: [0] Allocated Port for 172.16.1.3 -> 41.224.0.1: wanted 1043 got 1043
*Mar 1 00:20:24.607: NAT*: i: tcp (172.16.1.3, 1043) -> (41.224.0.3, 80) [176]
*Mar 1 00:20:24.611: NAT*: i: tcp (172.16.1.3, 1043) -> (41.224.0.3, 80) [176]
*Mar 1 00:20:24.611: NAT*: s=172.16.1.3->41.224.0.1, d=41.224.0.3 [176]
*Mar 1 00:20:24.635: NAT*: o: tcp (41.224.0.3, 80) -> (41.224.0.1, 1043) [1098]
*Mar 1 00:20:24.639: NAT*: s=41.224.0.3, d=41.224.0.1->172.16.1.3 [1098]
*Mar 1 00:20:24.639: NAT*: i: tcp (172.16.1.3, 1043) -> (41.224.0.3, 80) [177]
*Mar 1 00:20:24.639: NAT*: s=172.16.1.3->41.224.0.1, d=41.224.0.3 [177] R1#
*Mar 1 00:20:44.811: NAT*: o: tcp (41.224.0.3, 80) -> (41.224.0.1, 1043) [1107]
*Mar 1 00:20:44.815: NAT*: s=41.224.0.3, d=41.224.0.1->172.16.1.3 [1107]
*Mar 1 00:20:44.847: NAT*: i: tcp (172.16.1.3, 1043) -> (41.224.0.3, 80) [178]
*Mar 1 00:20:44.847: NAT*: s=172.16.1.3->41.224.0.1, d=41.224.0.3 [178]
*Mar 1 00:20:44.851: NAT: i: tcp (172.16.1.3, 1043) -> (41.224.0.3, 80) [179]
*Mar 1 00:20:44.851: NAT: s=172.16.1.3->41.224.0.1, d=41.224.0.3 [179] R1#
*Mar 1 00:20:47.967: NAT*: i: tcp (172.16.1.3, 1043) -> (41.224.0.3, 80) [180]
*Mar 1 00:20:47.967: NAT*: s=172.16.1.3->41.224.0.1, d=41.224.0.3 [180] R1#
*Mar 1 00:20:53.747: NAT*: i: tcp (172.16.1.3, 1043) -> (41.224.0.3, 80) [181]
*Mar 1 00:20:53.747: NAT*: s=172.16.1.3->41.224.0.1, d=41.224.0.3 [181] R1#
*Mar 1 00:21:05.107: NAT*: i: tcp (172.16.1.3, 1043) -> (41.224.0.3, 80) [182]
*Mar 1 00:21:05.111: NAT*: s=172.16.1.3->41.224.0.1, d=41.224.0.3 [182] R1#
*Mar 1 00:21:27.723: NAT*: i: tcp (172.16.1.3, 1043) -> (41.224.0.3, 80) [183]
*Mar 1 00:21:27.723: NAT*: s=172.16.1.3->41.224.0.1, d=41.224.0.3 [183]
```

**Router R3:**

```
*Mar 1 00:20:55.247: NAT*: o: tcp (41.224.0.1, 1043) -> (41.224.0.3, 80) [176]
*Mar 1 00:20:55.251: NAT*: o: tcp (41.224.0.1, 1043) -> (41.224.0.3, 80) [176]
*Mar 1 00:20:55.251: NAT*: s=41.224.0.1, d=41.224.0.3->172.16.5.66 [176]
*Mar 1 00:20:55.279: NAT*: i: tcp (172.16.5.66, 80) -> (41.224.0.1, 1043) [1098]
*Mar 1 00:20:55.283: NAT*: s=172.16.5.66->41.224.0.3, d=41.224.0.1 [1098]
*Mar 1 00:20:55.287: NAT*: o: tcp (41.224.0.1, 1043) -> (41.224.0.3, 80) [177]
*Mar 1 00:20:55.287: NAT*: s=41.224.0.1, d=41.224.0.3->172.16.5.66 [177] R3#
*Mar 1 00:21:15.291: NAT*: i: tcp (172.16.5.66, 80) -> (41.224.0.1, 1043) [1107]
*Mar 1 00:21:15.291: NAT*: s=172.16.5.66->41.224.0.3, d=41.224.0.1 [1107]
*Mar 1 00:21:15.351: NAT*: o: tcp (41.224.0.1, 1043) -> (41.224.0.3, 80) [178]
*Mar 1 00:21:15.355: NAT*: s=41.224.0.1, d=41.224.0.3->172.16.5.66 [178]
*Mar 1 00:21:15.355: NAT*: o: tcp (41.224.0.1, 1043) -> (41.224.0.3, 80) [179]
*Mar 1 00:21:15.355: NAT*: s=41.224.0.1, d=41.224.0.3->172.16.5.66 [179] R3#
*Mar 1 00:21:18.523: NAT*: o: tcp (41.224.0.1, 1043) -> (41.224.0.3, 80) [180]
*Mar 1 00:21:18.527: NAT*: s=41.224.0.1, d=41.224.0.3->172.16.5.66 [180] R3#
*Mar 1 00:21:24.291: NAT*: o: tcp (41.224.0.1, 1043) -> (41.224.0.3, 80) [181]
*Mar 1 00:21:24.291: NAT*: s=41.224.0.1, d=41.224.0.3->172.16.5.66 [181] R3#
*Mar 1 00:21:35.651: NAT*: o: tcp (41.224.0.1, 1043) -> (41.224.0.3, 80) [182]
*Mar 1 00:21:35.651: NAT*: s=41.224.0.1, d=41.224.0.3->172.16.5.66 [182] R3#
*Mar 1 00:21:58.123: NAT*: o: tcp (41.224.0.1, 1043) -> (41.224.0.3, 80) [183]
*Mar 1 00:21:58.123: NAT*: s=41.224.0.1, d=41.224.0.3->172.16.5.66 [183] R3#
*Mar 1 00:22:42.831: NAT*: o: tcp (41.224.0.1, 1043) -> (41.224.0.3, 80) [185]
*Mar 1 00:22:42.831: NAT*: s=41.224.0.1, d=41.224.0.3->172.16.5.66 [185]
```

Comment: I think you need to clear up a few things. When you say, "_checking the server, I can't even ping on the router R3 (172.16.5.65) _," you should make it clear where you are pinging from, and where you are pinging to. Are you trying to use the ping command on R3 to somewhere else? Also you say, "_the interface e0_," but you don't specify on which device.

Comment: @RonMaupin checkig the server means pining from the server to R3 router, or vice-versa.
the interface e0 on the R3 router which is directly connected to the server.